# GTFS in OpenTripPlanner

Tags: xml, gtfs, opentripplanner

Iam Working on a tripplanner, i got a problem, that my GTFS won't work.
The OSM files is loaded in correctly, the tripplanner now makes the fastest route from point A to B, but it does not take busses into consideration. Only walking.

My GTFS file is here:   http://www.rkt.no/gt/google_transit.zip.

Iam using OpenTripPlanner.

Any idea what i can do to make it work?
Thank you for answers.

Here is what my graph-builder.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="gtfsBuilder" class="org.opentripplanner.graph_builder.impl.GtfsGraphBuilderImpl">
        <property name="gtfsBundles">
            <bean id="gtfsBundles" class="org.opentripplanner.graph_builder.model.GtfsBundles">
                <property name="bundles">
                    <list>
                        <bean class="org.opentripplanner.graph_builder.model.GtfsBundle">
                            <property name="path" value="C:\Users\Mesel\Downloads\google_transit.stops.zip" />


                            <!-- By default, bikes may only be taken along on transit trips if the GTFS data allows them to be.
                                 If the GTFS data doesn't contain appropriate data, but the actual transit trips do allows bikes
                                 to be taken along, a defaultBikesAllowed property may be specified to allow bikes.
                             -->
                            <property name="defaultBikesAllowed" value="true" />
                        </bean>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>

        <!-- GTFS-rt ALERTS -->
        <property name="gtfsGraphBuilders">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.opentripplanner.graph_builder.impl.transit_index.TransitIndexBuilder" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Configure the GraphBuilderTask -->
    <bean id="graphBuilderTask" class="org.opentripplanner.graph_builder.GraphBuilderTask">
        <!-- The path where the graph bundle will be written -->
        <property name="path" value="C:/otp" />
        <property name="graphBuilders">
            <list>
                <!-- Include an OpenStreetMap graph builder plugin -->
                <bean class="org.opentripplanner.graph_builder.impl.osm.OpenStreetMapGraphBuilderImpl">
                    <property name="provider">
                        <!-- Use an OSM provider that will automatically download OSM data in a specified region -->
                        <bean class="org.opentripplanner.openstreetmap.impl.RegionBasedOpenStreetMapProviderImpl">
                            <property name="regionsSource">
                                <!-- The region to collect OSM data -->
                                <bean class="org.opentripplanner.openstreetmap.impl.FixedRegionSourceImpl">
                                    <property name="latFrom" value="58.896" />
                                    <property name="lonFrom" value="5.70873" />
                                    <property name="latTo" value="58.9122" />
                                    <property name="lonTo" value="5.75117" />
                                </bean>
                            </property>
                            <!-- Specify where downloaded OSM data will be cached -->
                            <property name="cacheDirectory" value="C:/otp/test" />
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                    <property name="defaultWayPropertySetSource">
                        <bean class="org.opentripplanner.graph_builder.impl.osm.DefaultWayPropertySetSource" />
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: xml file seems to be correct, i changed some of the paths to cacheDirectory and used a online gtfs file not a locally one.