# Gtfs files wont work in Open Trip Planner

Tags: opentripplanner

My question is a duplicate of this question:
[GTFS in OpenTripPlanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814555/gtfs-in-opentripplanner)

, but there arent any solutions in that answer.

My gtfs are loaded correctly and the stops do appear on the map. But OTP doesnt
take into account the bus routes only walking and driving. My city doesnt provide gtfs so i made them myself using the data from the local agency.

The data that I use:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1WCIwoXc9RxeRujWA46KU6u2Nce3yReK9

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked your GTFS files and it seems that they are not 100% valid. To reproduce and solve this issue, I recommend you downloading the latest release of [MobilityData/gtfs-validator](https://github.com/MobilityData/gtfs-validator) (requires Java 11 or newer to be installed). This validator provides a GUI and a CLI; I used the CLI by running the following command:

```
java -jar bin/gtfs-validator-4.0.0-cli.jar -i ioannina.gtfs.zip -o validator-results
```

This reads ioannina.gtfs.zip, validates that data, and writes the results (with a fully detailed explanation of the problems) into the folder "validator-results". You can read the results by opening the "results.html" in that folder.

Once you have removed all errors from your gtfs-data, run again opentripplanner, but make sure that the name of your .zip follows [OTP´s naming conventions](https://opentripplanner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Basic-Tutorial/) (*"name must end in .zip and must contain the letters 'gtfs'"*).

Comment: Thanks for the help. But i was able to fix them.